# How to determine on which side of the wall object is placed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I can't seem to figure out how to detect on which side of the wall object is placed.

When z axis is positive it works fine in both cases (left side wall and bottom wall)

[Image of the situation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-Iqb0YfG0dtUk1naTB1SEppSzg/view?usp=sharing)

But when object is placed on right side wall or top wall the z axis value should be negative for it to be in the room and that's what I can't figure out. How to determine on which side of the wall the object is?

[Image of the situation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-Iqb0YfG0dtbTUtRV9xY21oVm8/view?usp=sharing)

And here's the code that I'm using to place the object

```
private void placeObjectToWall(GameObject obj){
        GameObject wall = getRandomGameObject (walls);
        obj.transform.parent = wall.transform;
        float forward = 0;
        if(wall.transform.rotation.y%180!=0){
            forward = obj.transform.localScale.x/2;
        }else{
            forward = obj.transform.localScale.z/2;
        }
        obj.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0,0,forward);
}
```

Comment: Give more information about walls etc...

Comment: Wall is just a cube tagged "Wall" which is a child of empty gameobject (called Room1). `obj` is also tagged as "Wall" meaning that it goes to one of the walls.

Comment: Here's the structure of the room [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-Iqb0YfG0dtZjhqYkFvaTVyc3M/view?usp=sharing) Ceiling and Ground have other generated objects as their childs but that should not matter in this case.

Comment: Currently I added a transparent cube to the center of the ground so that I can position the walls but this is certainly not a good solution and will give me trouble when going to more than 4 walls.

Answer (score 0):

For determine the side to the left or right wall, you can make a Vector3 from the center of your object to the center the right wall and other Vector3 from the center of your object to the center the left one.

If these Vector3 has the same direction, the object is outside the walls, but if they don't have the same direction, the object is inside the walls.

For determine the side to ceiling and floor walls, you can do the same but with these walls, with the same conclusions.

Here you have these vector representations on your images.

[image]

[image]

Note that when I say "the same direction" I mean that these vectors are both positive or negative, not that the are the same.

Comment: If I understand you suggestion correctly I need to know two walls (right and left) but during generation I only know one of them